# How to switch from a Slack team account to another

Tags: user-accounts, slack, user-switching

A collaborator recently invited me to a Slack workspace I was already subscribed to, which I thought was weird but I accepted.

I just found that my original account was using my `xxx@gmail.com` address and he invited me with my `xxx@company.com` address.
I am now logged with the company email address and I don't find how to:

- completely log out
- switch to another account based on the email address

I guess Slack is not made to use with multiple team accounts for 1 user but I feel locked in this accidental situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found how to switch account:

1. In the workspace, click on the workspace name *(top-left corner)*
2. At the bottom of the menu, click *"Log out from: **workspace**"*
3. Confirm on the web page that opened. Then click *"Log in back"*
4. Enter the email & password to log in with the other account.

---

> *I use Slack in another language, I translated the menu items as I read them.*